# How can I configure Postfix to silently drop/discard/reject mails that were sent from specific users to an external address?

Tags: email, postfix, mta

How can I configure Postfix to silently drop/discard/reject mails that were sent from specific users to an external address?
It should work only for specific users

E.g:

1. abc@localdomain can send mail to only @localdomain users.
2. abc@localdomain can only receive from  @localdomain users.

Comment: move your question to serverfualt at http://serverfault.com ,

Answer (score 1):

you should use address rewriting : http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html

Comment: In Over organization we have 2 domain with single database. e.g localdomain1 and localdomain2 . we want to restrict some specific  users which is on localdomain2(users@localdomain2) to send and receive mail form localdomain1 .  it means localdomain2 users can send and receive mail within localdomain2 only.